# Break on textarea value change

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I know how to break on the value change of an `input` element (Break on Attribute Change) but how do I break whenever the value changes of a `textarea` DOM element, since the value attribute is not exposed to the html?

Comment: I just tried Break on Attribute Change with SO's Answer textarea, and it hit the breakpoint.

Comment: SO code must be editing the CSS as well when you type or something like that because it's not working in my textarea

Comment: You're right, I just tried it in a fiddle and it didn't break.

Comment: As a workaround, you could add a `change` listener function to the textarea, and put a breakpoint in the function.